# Is it possible to move vertices of a regular polygon to shape a given convex polygon?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

can vertices of a regular polygon (n-gon) in the plane be moved (slide) one at a time to form a given convex polygon so that the polygons in between remain convex?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let's do it the other way, starting with your favorite convex polygon. Choose a point inside the convex polygon and a circle completely outside the polygon, and then continuously expand the polygon radially away from the central point until the vertices hit the surrounding circle. (I suppose it takes some thought to justify why all these intermediate polygons will still be convex. Perhaps they could be slid one at a time starting with the vertex closest to the circle.) Once the vertices are all on the same circle, they can be slid around the circle itself until the polygon is regular.

Comment: thats a good idea , thanks martin